# Can a planeswalker ability be activated in response to another spell or ability?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I cast a [Lightning Helix](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLightning%20Helix%5d) targeting my opponent's [Gideon, Ally of Zendikar](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGideon%2c%20Ally%20of%20Zendikar%5d) on his upkeep with it having 3 Loyalty, can he in response use Gideon's plus 1 ability to put it out of Lightning Helix's range?

Answer (score 10):

No, a player can't activate loyalty abilities during his upkeep nor in response to spells or abilities. Loyalty abilities can be activated at "sorcery speed", only during a player's main phase. The specific rule from the Comprehensive rules is:

> 606.3. A player may activate a loyalty ability of a permanent they control **any time they have priority and the stack is empty during a main phase of their turn**, but only if no player has previously activated a loyalty ability of that permanent that turn.

Comment: Teferi, Temporal Archmage is the only exception to that rule, but it is stated quite explicitly.

Answer (score -2):

You can [Only] if, you have either Teferi, Temporal Archmage's <-10>Emblem or Teferi's Talent Enchanted Planeswalker's <-12>Emblem.

Comment: For what it's worth, we've generally found that answers to MtG questions saying "unless you use (insert specific card here)" are generally not that well-received, unless of course that is specifically what the question is asking for - MtG is such a broad game that there's a card which gives an exception to _every_ rule.